# why name of user authenticate does not show in template using angular?

Tags: angular

I want to display authenticated user in my template, and even it displays in console, it does not display in template.

**chat.component.ts**

```
  constructor(private tokenService:TokenService,private profileService:ProfileService) {  
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testWebSocketsConnection();
    this.userAuth();
  } 

     userAuth(){
        this.profileService.getUser(this.id).subscribe((user:any) => {
          console.log(user);
          this.user = user.data; 
        })
      }
```

**chat.component.html**

```
 <header class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4 mb-4">Username : {{ user?.name }}</h1>
  </header>
```

[image: user auth info]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `console.log(user);` logs the actual object of your user and there is no `data` property present, your assignment should be:

```
this.user = user;
```